# Need help fixing error with confirming payment on Stripe (React-Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I need help with fixing this error I am facing, it is:

Payment confirmation error:, Object {
"code": "Failed",
"declineCode": null,
"localizedMessage": "Card details not complete",
"message": "Card details not complete",
"stripeErrorCode": null,
"type": null,
}

My api code is:

```
app.post('/create-payment-intent', async (req, res) => {
    const { amount, stripeCustomerId } = req.body;

    try {
        // Retrieve the customer to get the default payment method
        const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(stripeCustomerId);
        const defaultPaymentMethodId = customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method;

        if (!defaultPaymentMethodId) {
            return res.status(400).send({ error: 'No default payment method found for the customer' });
        }

        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: amount,
            currency: 'usd',
            customer: stripeCustomerId,
            payment_method: defaultPaymentMethodId,
            confirm: true,
            off_session: true, // Set to true if the customer is not present
        });

        res.send({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating payment intent:', error);
        res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
    }
});
```

My function is being called on a TouchabileOpacity in a React Component:

```
const handleConfirmPayment = async () => {
        console.log('Starting payment confirmation...');
    
        if (!selectedPaymentMethodId) {
            console.log('No payment method selected.');
            Alert.alert('Error', 'No payment method selected');
            return;
        }
    
        console.log(`Selected payment method ID: ${selectedPaymentMethodId}`);
    
        try {
            console.log('Creating payment intent...');
            const response = await axios.post('/create-payment-intent', {
                amount: 3006, // Amount in cents ($30.00)
                stripeCustomerId: "id", // Ensure this is dynamically retrieved
                paymentMethodId: selectedPaymentMethodId,
            });
    
            console.log('Payment intent response:', response.data);
        
            const { clientSecret } = response.data;
        
            if (!clientSecret) {
                console.error('Failed to get client secret from the backend');
                Alert.alert('Payment failed', 'Unable to process the payment.');
                return;
            }
    
            console.log(`Confirming payment with client secret: ${clientSecret}`);
            const { error } = await confirmPayment(clientSecret, {
                paymentMethodType: 'Card', 
                paymentMethodId: selectedPaymentMethodId,
            });
    
            if (error) {
                console.error('Payment confirmation error:', error);
                Alert.alert('Payment failed', error.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Payment successful!');
                Alert.alert('Payment successful', 'Your payment was successful!');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Payment error:', error);
            Alert.alert('Payment failed', 'There was an issue with your payment.');
        }
    };
```

However, when I click on the TouchableOpacity, it prints this in the console:

```
Starting payment confirmation...
Selected payment method ID: "actualID"
Creating payment intent...
Payment intent response: Object {
  "clientSecret": "actualsecret",
}
Confirming payment with client secret: "actualsecret"

Payment confirmation error:, Object {
  "code": "Failed",
  "declineCode": null,
  "localizedMessage": "Card details not complete",
  "message": "Card details not complete",
  "stripeErrorCode": null,
  "type": null,
}
```

The weird this is that in the stripe dashboard, I do get the payment as a success in the status and it looks like it went through. But after some time on the click of the TouchableOpacity, there is a popup error of "Payment failed. Card details not complete". Not sure why it goes through, but then I get an error? How can I fix this? I am also using the default payment method on the confirmPayment function offered by stripe react native package. Also, I am not using the stripe's provided payment sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/modules/PaymentIntent.html#CardParams

```
{ paymentMethodType: "Card"; paymentMethodData?: { token?: string; billingDetails?: BillingDetails; mandateData?: MandateData } } | { paymentMethodType: "Card"; paymentMethodData: { paymentMethodId: string; cvc?: string; billingDetails?: BillingDetails; mandateData?: MandateData } }
```

paymentMethodId property should be inside paymentMethodData object

Try passing this to the confirmPayment method

```
await confirmPayment(clientSecret, {
                paymentMethodType: 'Card', 
                paymentMethodData: {
                  paymentMethodId: selectedPaymentMethodId},
                });
```